# Javascript: What is the syntax to select children of any element?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am writing code and I came up to issue where I need to select something other than `firstChild`, but I don't know the syntax to write this code. I scoured online hoping to find some API documentation on them but have found nothing. What is the code to select other child elements? Like say I wanted to select the 4th child in a element, what is the code for that? I only know the code to select the 1st child element.

```
dom.el("playeravatar").firstChild.innerHTML = '<img src="dwarfs/dwarf14.jpg" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: auto" alt="Dwarf">';
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children

Comment: You may also be interested in getting and using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: @louisbros has the right answer, but also, I would say that in my experience, good code is not often looking precisely for "element 4". It's either looping through all of them, or retrieving elements by class, ID, or other identifier regardless of DOM positioning.

Comment: You should definitively use more jQuery

Answer (score 2):

You can use DOM object `children` which provide you all children of an element.

For example if you want get the property `text` of the third children (0,1, 2) of an element called `playeravatar`, you code should be:

```
var c = document.getElementById("playeravatar").children[2].text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery selector **`:nth-child(n)`** for example if you need to select the 4th child in a element use **`:nth-child(4)`**

```
<div id="parent">
  <div>
    <span>first-child</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>second-child</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>third-child</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>fourth-child</span>
  </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
      alert($("#parent div:nth-child(4)").html());
      $("#parent div:nth-child(4)").html('<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>');
});
```

Comment: This code are not JavaScript